# Разные по смыслу данные в разных таблицах, или мешать пирожки с утюгами?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Что важнее и правильнее, хранить данные одного типа в одной таблице, даже если они разные по смыслу и нужны в разных разделах сайта или разделять данные разного смысла по разным таблицам, даже если они одного типа? Например

вариант 1 (разные по смыслу данные в одной таблице):

```
ID | Name
1  | Пирожок 1
2  | Пирожок 2
3  | Утюг 1
4  | Утюг 2
5  | Пирожок 3
```

Вариант 2 (Разные по смыслу данные в разных таблицах):

таблица с пирожками

```
ID | Name
1  | Пирожок 1
2  | Пирожок 2
3  | Пирожок 3
```

таблица с утюгами

```
ID | Name
1  | Утюг 1
2  | Утюг 2
```

Я слышал, что пирожки с утюгами, если одного типа, то должны быть в одной таблице (вариант 1). Но если в бизнес логике приложения утюги с пирожками никогда не пересекаются, и всякий раз когда мне потребуется пирожок, я буду сперва в таблице его отфильтровывать от утюгов - это нормально? Вы скажите, не переживай, результаты фильтрации закэшируются, но и я вам отвечу, не переживайте, чего плохого в одной дополнительной таблице?

Comment: Ну сэкономите 0.000001 секунду времени, Вам от этого легче жить станет? Данные хранятся по логике применения. Если у Вас 2 справочника разных - замечательно, главное, чтобы потом тянуть не пришлось вместе, если вдруг резко понадобится. А если таких справочников резко станет под 100 штук, то удачи вспоминать потом, что к чему)))

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar  согласен, но при этом, если у нас есть таблица с покупателями и вторая таблица с товарами, в теории может быть так, что в обеих таблицах только по 2 столбца, id и name, нам следует объединить пользователей и товары в одну таблицу? Если нет, то где та грань и что нужно учитывать решая разделять данные с разной логикой (или разным смыслом) или нет?

Comment: Нужно логику наперед предугадать. Если у Вас будут товары и покупатели лежать в одной таблице (даже если предположим, что перепутать данные невозможно), тогда при хотя бы малейшем изменении структуры данных (от покупателей стали требовать адрес доставки, а к товарам захотели добавлять описание) уже будет проблема, потому что не везде нужно описание и не везде нужны адреса. Если это данные, которые меняются предельно редко (как раз справочники хорошо к такой логике подходят) — можно всё в кучу (опять же, как-то нужно указывать типы, чтобы разделять утюги от Иванов).

Comment: Либо это экземпляры одной сущности - тогда одна таблица, и пофиг на непохожесть, либо это разные сущности - тогда разные таблицы,  будь они хоть омонимы.

Comment: Вы сами написали «Разные по смыслу данные в разных таблицах». Если утюги и пироги по смыслу это одно и то же, например, товары, то в одной таблице. А если утюги это инструменты для выпечки пирогов, то разные.